# skb and Scatter gather feature

Tags: networking, linux-kernel, device-driver, linux-device-driver

I have few questions related to the SKB.

when we try to allocate a skb using alloc_skb( ) all the headers related to the skb will be allocated, for example a l4 header,l3 header,l2 header etc.,
I have seen sizeof(struct sk_buff) as 188. this must with all the header -- Am I correct?

The content of skb is going to contiguous with all the headers.(considering a liner skb without any fragments). correct?

Scatter gather(SG) - a hardware feature used to fetch data from different memory locations to copy(DMA) to device memory.

If the skb is going to be liner and if it is within the MTU size, SG will not be used. ?

If the skb is non-liner and if the size exceeds MTU size, SG will be used.

When we wil hit skb as non-linear case, in the sense skb having multiple fragments. Please confirm?

Thanks,
Kumar

Comment: sock_alloc_send_pskb() seems to use a fragment per page.

Answer (score 2):

I am trying to understand your question.

When you use alloc_skb - you specify the size of the data your would like to accomodate for in the skb structure itself. **This is commonly used for network headers**.

The scatter-gather lists inside the skb is commonly used for the *data* payload of your packet.

This means that if you have a bunch of data sitting in memory, you can create the skb, allowing space for the headers, and write the headers inside the skb itself - the use the SG entries to point to your data, eliminating the need to *copy* it.

The concept of "MTU" has nothing to do with SG being used or not.

If you "skb_put" data into your skb - it will be transmitted with the packet. If you add elements to you SG, they will be transmitted to.

Comment: Data doesn't usually go into S/G IO fragments unless the main skbuff buffer has already filled a page, at least for send operations on TCP and UDP, see tcp_sendmsg()/udp_sendmsg().